# Mobile Background is Dynamic

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

The background image I have setup works fine in web browser, it stays static, but on mobile the background is constantly changing depending on the height of content?

When the content is short on mobile the background isnt zoomed in but basically shows the left Third of the photo. When the content is long paragraph it is a much more zoomed portion of the first third of the photo.

I am currently using the current css

```
background-image: url("/images/midgame.jpg");
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the background image to zoom in or out, remove the `background-size: cover`
Also try `background-position: center top`

Comment: The image became a little more zoomed on the computer, but on mobile it repeats itself as you scroll down?

Comment: use `background-repeat: no-repeat` to avoid repeating

Answer (score 0):

Set explicit dimensions so that the background image appears when there is little or no content. Set `height:100%`. Might have to set width as well.

EDIT:

1. Remove `background-attachment:fixed`
2. Add `min-height:500px` or whatever number you wish.

Comment: Did not seem to change anything :S

Comment: The background completely disappeared when I remove and added those lines of css :S

Comment: Apologies. Since you already have background:cover, you don't need background:center center or background:center fixed.